# Would hiding OpenID on profile pages be a good idea?

Tags: feature-request, status-norepro, profile-page, openid

I'm using a domain name which includes my full given name and the first character of my first name. This information isn't typically available to SO, and I'd prefer that it stay that way.

Are there any reasons against hiding users' OpenID handles in their profiles? I would like for showing OpenID handles to be optional.

Comment: For clarity, this is what I see when looking at your profile page: http://img160.imageshack.us/img160/4692/soprofile.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any real logical reason why it HAS to be displayed. I agree that it should at the very least be a preference to show or not (perhaps hidden by default).

**Edit** Actually it is hidden to other users. You can see yours in your profile, but not others, so this is more or less just something that needs to be closed as "not actually a problem"

**Edit 2** if this is asking for the ability to -make- it visible, I don't have a problem with it, but I don't find much use for it overall.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see what your OpenID handle is. (Or am i misunderstanding the question?)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for other people to know this, so why tell them? For the same reason, your e-mail (generally used for site admin) isn't public unless you repeat it in your free text area.

If you want it public, put it there - see [my profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell), for example.